# Why in C++ is stack space allocated for local variable declarations never encountered by the thread of execution?

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow

Why in C++ is stack space allocated for local variable declarations never encountered by the thread of execution? Or, if left undefined by the C++ standard, why do certain compilers allocate stack space for local variable declarations never encountered by the thread of execution? Could a compiler only allocate stack space for variable declarations encountered by the thread of execution and still work?

To illustrate, calling this function in Debug mode where variable chars cannot be encountered results in a stack overflow:

```
void f()
{
    if (false)
    {
        char chars[INT_MAX];
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `cannot be encountered`?

Comment: The stack overflows because a large local variable is allocated. The question is why does this occur even though the code which declares this variable should be unreacable?

Comment: Keep in mind that the C++ standard defines the semantics of each language construct and requires the implementation (compiler) to make sure the program, when run, respects those semantics.  If the compiler can prove that removing a large chunk of unreachable code does not semantically alter the program, then it is free to remove it.  If you are getting a stack overflow, you're probably building in debug mode.  Compile in release mode and turn on all optimizations.  I'm sure the stack overflow will dissapear.

Comment: Jonathan Wood: I don't know of any OS allocates 2Gb of stack space, which is what is allocated by the local variable in that function. Then again, I don't CHECK such things very often because I don't actually try to do insane things like creating 2Gb of local variables...

Comment: By using Debug mode you're turning off all optimizations, which prevents the compiler from realizing the `if(false)` block is dead code.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) There's no reason not to. The C++ standard does not promise that variables inside scopes that are not entered during execution will not have space allocated for them.

2) It's faster and simpler. If all the locals get allocated at once, the code to allocate space for locals consists of a one update to the stack pointer at the beginning of the function, and one at the end. If locals within a scope have to be allocated and deallocated at the beginning and end of that scope, you get a lot more stack pointer updates.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler has hoisted the declaration of the local variable. Whether this is done is not defined by the standard, hence the behaviour is **implementation specific**. Doing so allows the space for all the local variables to be allocated at once, which reduces overhead.

However, with optimisation, the compiler will identify your particular case as dead code and what you are encountering will be eliminated.

Comment: Hoisting also makes `goto` much less complicated to implement.

Comment: Yes, this is a good point. Instead of adjusting the stack pointer at each scope, it only needs to be done at function entry/exit.

Comment: Note that the variable is POD; you can't hoist the initialization of an object when it has a ctor with side-effects. However, even then you can hoist the stack pointer adjustment.

Answer (score 4):

This would be extremely compiler and optimization-level dependent.  Some compilers would be able to tell that the if-block there would never be reached, and thus not emit code for it at all.  Others would.  Others may depend on optimization level.  Still others allocate the space for all local variables when a function is called, rather than when the scope is entered because it's "simpler" to calculate.  This is actually similar to vanilla C behavior as there you MUST declare all variables at the beginning of functions (not sure if enclosing scopes with scope-local variables exist in vanilla C, been a long time), so it may be a hold-over from that.

Also, you're obviously encountering that the stack is FAR smaller than the heap, and how local variable declaration can exceed its capacity, but I'm pretty sure that's the intention of your example.

If you're looking for a better "why did they do that" then post the compiler version (and settings) you're using for this, and maybe one of the creators will respond.  Without that, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

In case of MSVC a compiler warning(C4101) is issued at unused local variables. More details at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c733d5h9(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler and the settings you use. For example (I had to modify this so it would actually compile in VS 2008), the following will throw a stack overflow exception in Debug but finish in Release:

```
void f()
{
    if (false)
    {
        char chars[INT_MAX/2];
    }
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```